# Voltar posição anterior no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio

Quando estamos querendo ver algum método, pressionamos F12 e logo somos "transportados" ao referido método. Acontece que esse método pode estar em outro projeto ou outro formulário ou em um *user control* e etc aí vem a pergunta. Há alguma tecla de atalho que me faça voltar para onde eu estava antes de pressionar o F12? Um tipo de undo. Há como?

Comment: Já tentou `CRTL +`? Não sei se funciona entre janelas. Se não der, pelo menos `CTRL TAB` ou `CTRL SHIFT TAB` ajuda?

Comment: Não, não é isso. O Shift+Tab navega entre janelas abertas no windows, certo? Eu falo dentro de um projeto eu navegar entre os métodos. Com F12 eu vou ao método e depois com uma tecla ou um conjunto, eu quero voltar para onde eu estava.

Comment: Não, você tentou fazer o que eu passei? Que resultado deu em cada um?

Comment: CTRL+Tab dá certo

Comment: E o `CTRL +` deu certo também?

Comment: Não, não consegui nada com o Ctrl+

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uma forma é simplesmente usar O <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> para navegar entre as TABS.

Ou pode usar <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, para voltar ao ponto onde estava. Ele significa *Navigate Backward*.

[Referência de atalhos](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 11):

Utilize os seguintes comandos respectivamente Ctrl, +, -.

Existe um botão no Menu que faz o mesmo procedimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]